# Multiplication mod 2 without extra registers

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, circuits

For an arbitrary bitstring $(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ and an $n\times n$ invertible binary matrix $M$ (fixed ahead of time), I would like to construct a circuit $C$ acting on these $n$ bits whose output will be such a bitstring $(y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n)$ that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \ldots \\ y_n
\end{pmatrix}
= M
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \ldots \\ x_n
\end{pmatrix} \bmod 2 \ ,
$$
The extra registers are not allowed. The circuit $C$ should only contain $NOT$ and $CNOT$ gates (where $CNOT(x, y) = (x, x+y \bmod 2) $). The matrix $M$ is such that it permits for a reversible calculation.

The lower bound is trivially given by $O(n^2)$ operations. (That's how you would usually multiply matrices, if you had access to the original values of registers all the time. The question, however, is inspired by quantum computation, where one cannot store the initial values, and extra qubits are expensive.)

A known fact from quantum information is that such circuit can be constructed with at most $O(\exp(n))$ gates. The goal is to design it using a sub-exponential number of gates.

Comment: You cannot construct such a circuit at all, since matrix multiplication is not linear. Even when $n = 1$ this is impossible. You cannot express AND using only NOT and XOR.

Comment: Sorry! Used wrong notation.

Comment: Can you possible explain your model in full? Assume I don't know anything about quantum computation. What is the input, what is the desired output, and what operations are allowed? Try to be as verbose as possible. Don't assume anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix multiplication is not linear"?

Comment: The function $Mx$ is not a linear function of the bits of $M$ and $x$. Even when $n = 1$. You can only compute linear functions using NOT and XOR.

Comment: I think I understand the source of confusion. The circuit $C$ of logical gates should represent multiplying the input bitstring by a particular matrix $M$. The question is how to optimally construct $M\mapsto C$.

Comment: $Mx$ is a linear function of $x$...

Comment: So the matrix $M$ is fixed in advance, and you are given $n$ registers, initially holding $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and want to change them to $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, using only the operations NOT and CNOT? Note this is only potentially possible if $M$ is regular.

Comment: I believe, it's possible for an arbitrary matrix. Consider the following algorithm. For the first register, the multiplication is trivial - we just add to it all such registers $j$ which correspond to $M_{1,j}=1$. For the second register, while adding the (new) first register (if $M_{2,1} \neq 0$), we also need to compensate for all the changes which have been made to the first one by adding them to the second. The remaining registers are added in a usual way. And so on, while adding the "modified" registers we can always account for changes made in those.

Comment: If all your operations are reversible, and given $x$ you are computing $Mx$, then the operation $x \mapsto Mx$ has to be reversible. I strongly suggest that you spell out the input, the output, and the allowed operations.

Comment: The input is an arbitrary bitstring $x$, the output is such a bitstring $y$ that $y=Mx$ for a given $M$. Since indeed only reversible operations are allowed, you're definitely right, there should be a restriction on $M$...

Comment: Instead of answering in the comments, please modify your question to include all relevant details that are necessary to answer it. Don't add an "EDIT:" section, simply add the relevant details to the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is solved by Patel, Markov and Hayes in their paper [Optimal synthesis of linear reversible circuits](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/pubs/jour/qic08-cnot.pdf). They mention a simple $\Omega(n^2/\log n)$ lower bound for the worst-case $M$, obtained by counting, and show that it is tight, in the sense that there is an $O(n^2/\log n)$ algorithm for any reversible $M$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: BTW, it's really amazing how the constraint of matrix reversibility allows one to reduce the number of gates from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n^2/\log n)$